# echoing mid execution is not being sent to the recipient

Tags: php, echo, ob-start, ob-get-contents

```
$output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo json_encode($data);
        ob_start();
        echo $output;
```

This code is called as an API from another server and I want to send the json data back to that server but I want to keep $output in the output buffer so later I can log it into a file.  The `json_encode($data);` is not being sent to the requesting script.  I have tried many variations using `flush()` and `ob_flush` but not have worked.  When I add `die()` immediately after the `json_encode($data);` line it works except I don't actually want it to `die()` at that moment. how can I fix this?

Comment: maybe using `ob_start()` before you `echo json_encode($data)` would do the trick as `ob_start()`  "Turn on output buffering" as said in the documentation

Comment: I think I tried that but I want to immediately send the `json_encode($data)` back to the server that requests this script so I don't want to use output buffering for this.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

Store the result in a variable, echo the variable, log the variable. No need for output buffering:

```
$output = json_encode($data);
echo $output;
log_to_whatever($output);
```

If you do want output buffering, then you should start buffering before you echo:

```
ob_start();
echo json_encode($data);
$output = ob_get_clean(); // Shorthand for get and clean
echo $output;
log_to_whatever($output);
```

Instead of cleaning the buffer you can actually flush the buffer (= send it to the client), but still get it into a variable too.

```
ob_start();
echo json_encode($data);
$output = ob_get_flush(); // Shorthand for get and flush
// echo $output; This is not needed anymore, because it is already flushed
log_to_whatever($output);
```

But in either case, it seems these are cumbersome alternatives for the simple first solution, at least in the scenario you presented.